# MYSQL/PHP/AJAX Search using SELECT, CONCAT, OR and LIKE on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select, concatenation

I'm makeing a search filed for a table that has 25+ columns in it. Two of them are a First Name and a Last name. I can get the CONCAT to search them fine alone but when I add the other OR selections I get errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help would be great.
More details:
I'm tring to figure this out here.. I have two different SELECT statments that are working fine #1 is

```
$query = "SELECT `CustomerID`, `CompanyName`, `ContactFirstName`, `ContactLastName`,
`BillingAddress`, `BillingAddress2`, `City`, `PostalCode`, `PhoneNumber`, `FaxNumber`, `EMail`
FROM `Customers` WHERE `CustomerID` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `CompanyName` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `ContactFirstName` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `ContactLastName` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `BillingAddress` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `BillingAddress2` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `PhoneNumber` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `EMail` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'";
```

And #2 is

```
SELECT *, CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName) AS FullName FROM `Customers` HAVING
FullName LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'";
```

I've been unable to figure out how to add the second select into the first one.

---EDIT---
After a1ex07's post I redid the query and it's working they way I was looking for...

```
$query = "SELECT `CustomerID`, `CompanyName`, `ContactFirstName`, `ContactLastName`, 
BillingAddress`, `BillingAddress2`, `City`,  `PostalCode`, `PhoneNumber`, `FaxNumber`, `EMail`
FROM `Customers`
WHERE `CustomerID` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `CompanyName` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `BillingAddress` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `BillingAddress2` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `City` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `PostalCode` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `PhoneNumber` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `FaxNumber` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `EMail` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName) LIKE 
'%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'";

$query_run = mysql_query($query);
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
$CustomerID = $query_row['CustomerID'];
$CompanyName = $query_row['CompanyName'];
$ContactFirstName = $query_row['ContactFirstName'];
$ContactLastName = $query_row['ContactLastName'];
$BillingAddress = $query_row['BillingAddress'];
$BillingAddress2 = $query_row['BillingAddress2'];
$City = $query_row['City'];
$PostalCode = $query_row['PostalCode'];
$PhoneNumber = $query_row['PhoneNumber'];
$FaxNumber = $query_row['FaxNumber'];
$EMail = $query_row['EMail'];

echo $CustomerID.' '.$CompanyName.' '.$ContactFirstName.' '.$ContactLastName.'
'.$BillingAddress.' '.$BillingAddress2.' '.$City.' '.$PostalCode.' '.$PhoneNumber.' 
'.$FaxNumber.' '.$EMail.'<br>';
```

It seems to be doing what I want, unless there would be a way to get the `FullName` variable back in?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with #2.

Comment: What errors do you get? We can't run your queries..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you well, you are trying to add `WHERE ... OR FullName LIKE ...` to the first query. It fails because you cannot use field aliases in `WHERE`. You need to do `WHERE ... OR CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName) LIKE ....`

**Updated**:

> It seems to be doing what I want, unless there would be a way to get the FullName variable back in?

Just add it to `SELECT` : 
`SELECT ..., CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName) AS FullName`.

Once again, the problem is that aliases cannot be used in `WHERE`. 
There are some ways to deal with it:

1. Use expression in `WHERE` : `SELECT ..., CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName) AS FullName
   WHERE ... OR CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName)`
2. Use alias in `HAVING` : `SELECT ..., CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName) AS FullName
   WHERE ... 
   HAVING FullName ...`
3. Use derived tables :
   `SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ..., CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName) AS FullName

    ...)a

   WHERE ... OR FullName ....`

Your final query should look like:

```
    $query = "SELECT `CustomerID`, `CompanyName`, `ContactFirstName`, `ContactLastName`, 
BillingAddress`, `BillingAddress2`, `City`,  `PostalCode`, 
 `PhoneNumber`, `FaxNumber`, `EMail`,  
 CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName) AS FullName
FROM `Customers`
WHERE `CustomerID` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `CompanyName` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `BillingAddress` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `BillingAddress2` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `City` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `PostalCode` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `PhoneNumber` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `FaxNumber` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR `EMail` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'
OR CONCAT_WS(' ',ContactFirstName,ContactLastName) LIKE 
'%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."%'";
```

Comment: You can use aliased fields. That's why he has `HAVING` keyword. Look the usage up in the MySQL manual.

Comment: MySQL allows aliased fields in WHERE clauses. It's a very handy extension to the SQL standard, which otherwise doesn't allow for it.

Comment: You cannot use aliases in `WHERE`. `An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column:` from  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html.

Comment: @N.B : If you read my answer I didn't say anything about aliases in `HAVING` which are valid.

Comment: Also, `It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed` From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html.

Comment: @a1ex07 can you please tell me where do you see a `WHERE` clause in query #2? And where do you see column aliases in query #1? Mont didn't use aliases in `WHERE` unless there's a query he didn't post in his original question.

Comment: As far as I understood the question he tried to append `FullName` (which is alias) from the second query  to `WHERE` clause from the first query. Also, from what I see in his updated question, that was the problem.

Comment: That's a Winner! Thanks a1ex07.

Answer (score 0):

On #1 What if you put a space after the single quote?  ' ";  In other words so your sql doesn't run together, proper spacing.

Also, echo your SQL and try look at it to see.